# How to raise pH without generating CO2

Tags: acid-base, biochemistry

What buffering chemical/supplement will reduce lactic acid for runners but not generate $\ce{CO2}$?  Sodium bicarbonate does so but causes gastric upset.

Comment: Trying to reduce lactic acid build up in the muscles is really messing with the body's biochemistry and feed-back loops.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this question has an answer.  First, [muscle soreness is not caused by lactic acid](http://lifehacker.com/5895140/10-stubborn-exercise-myths-that-wont-die-debunked-by-science).   Second, distance runners run aerobically, meaning very little lactic acid would be generated by running in the first place.  (Sprinters are the exception here.)  Third, even if lactic acid buildup was a problem (which it isn't), both the cellular cytoplasm and human bloodstream are very well-buffered.  The cytoplasm is primarily buffered by potassium glutamate and the circulation by bicarbonate (created from respiration).  Production of "lactic acid" would really be production of lactate salts.

Comment: Thank You , Curt . Would you have any suggestions of a supplement to help the "burn" felt in the muscles when a runner is tiring ?